# Highcharts Export to zip

Tags: javascript, canvas, highcharts, jszip

I have a button that exports all my highcharts into a zip.
At this moment after I press the button, a zip file is created and downloaded but is empty.

I tried to debug this and as far as I can see there is a problem with base_image.onload function. Am I wrong?

//here is an IF for a type of highcharts ex. piecharts

```
if (typeof pie_charts!='undefined') {
  $.each(pie_charts, function(key, value) {
    if ($('#graph'+key).length>0) {
      var optns = pieChart('#graph'+key, '', value, 1);
      getsvgsrc('#graph'+key, key, optns, function(src) {
        var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
          zip.file(key+'.png', src, {base64: true});
          resolve();
        })
        promises.push(promise);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

//here is the function that I think is something wrong about it.

```
function getsvgsrc(selector, name, optns, callback) {
 if ($(selector).length) {
    var chart = $(selector).highcharts();
    var svg = chart.getSVG(optns);
    var base_image = new Image();
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    svg = "data:image/svg+xml," + svg;
    base_image.onload = function() {
        canvas.width = base_image.width;
        canvas.height = base_image.height;
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.fillStyle = "white";
        context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        context.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0);
        var link = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        var src = link.substr(link.indexOf(',') + 1);
        callback(src)
    }
    base_image.src = svg;
  }
}
```

At this moment a zip file is generated but is empty.
I need to have all the charts from the paga as .png included on this .zip file.

Comment: Here is a debug of what I tried:

https://www.screencast.com/t/RsaoUq7nH -> console.log of charts
https://www.screencast.com/t/FctY8nBZR -> charts have some undefined and null values.

Comment: Could you please prepare a simple JSFiddle example with the 'export to a zip functionality' which generates an empty zip? Also, what library do you use to compress the files?